No. of ways a caravan of camels can be rearranged

How many ways are there to rearrange the 8 camels behind the lead camel in a caravan so that each of the 8 camels has a different camel in front of it?
(Source:- The Art of Enumerative Combinatorics ,by George Martin)

I am supposed to solve this using PIE, so if I number the camels as 1, 2....8, I realised I have to remove a lot of cases, and literally, my cases were very messy
However when I saw the answer as $8!- \binom{8}{1} 7! + \binom{8}{2} 6!- \binom{8}{3} 5!   ....$, I was surprised. Maybe I am missing something as the answer is very standard one for PIE
(If someone thinks language is not clear, then I would like to say that the same language is given in the book, as far I understand, it means that if the camels are numbered $1,2,3...8$, with 8 behind lead camel, then 2 should not be front of 1, 3 not in front of 2.... Lead camel not in front of 8 in the required arrangements

The problem as wrtiien makes no sense since all the camels are different from one another. If you [edit] the question to quote the problem exactly we may be able to help.

What does "such that each camel has a different camel in front of it" mean? To clarify, can you give examples of valid (and invalid) arrangements?

The question in the book has the same language, not my fault

@PrinceChoudhary The correct response to "this [paraphrased] question is confusing" isn't "I don't see the difference between what I've written here and the question in the book, so the confusion isn't my fault".  It's "oh, here's the literal word-for-word question as written in the book."  I found the question and copied it in place of your version.  There are at least three major differences between your version and the book version.

I agree with the other responses that the problem is poorly written.  Normally, I would wait for the OP (i.e. original poster) to clarify the problem.  However, the wording presented in the posted question, "each camel has a different camel in front of it" has the rhythmic brevity that you typically find in poorly composed problems.  So, I surmise that the OP has presented the problem's original wording, and that it is therefore pointless to ask the OP for clarification.
Also, assuming that my conjecture is accurate, I disagree with the downvote given to the OP.  The OP can not be expected to work on a problem that is not clearly stated, and the OP can not be expected to be familiar enough with these types of problems to reverse-engineer the problem composer's intent.
Anyway, the presented official solution makes reverse-engineering the problem not that bad.  I am assuming that the problem composer intended the following:

Initially, line up the camels in single file, and label the camels $~C_0, C_1, ~C_2, ~\cdots, ~C_8,~$ so that $~C_0~$ is at the head of the line, and $~C_k~$ is immediately behind $~C_{k-1},~$ for $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,8\}.$

The problem solver is then supposed to enumerate the number of ways of permuting the (assumed single-file) ordering of the camels so that $~C_0~$ remains at the head of the line, $~C_1~$ is not immediately behind $~C_0, ~C_2~$ is not immediately behind $~C_1, ~C_3~$ is not immediately behind $~C_2, ~\cdots,~$ and $~C_8~$ is not immediately behind $~C_7.$


See this article for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see this answer for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion formula.

Following the syntax in the 2nd Inclusion-Exclusion link above, the official solution can be derived as follows:
Let $~S~$ denote the collection of all ways of leaving $~C_0~$ at the head of the line and permuting the $~8~$ other camels, without any regard for which camel is immediately behind any other camel.  For
$~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,8\},~$ let $~S_k~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ where $~C_k~$ is immediately behind $~C_{k-1}.$
Then, the desired computation is
$$| ~S ~| - | ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_8 ~|. \tag1 $$

Let $~T_0~$ denote $~| ~S ~|.$
For $~r \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~8 ~\},~$ 
let $~T_r~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 8} | ~S_{i_1} ~\cap ~S_{i_2} ~\cap ~\cdots ~\cap ~S_{i_r} ~|.$ 
That is, $~T_r~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{r} ~$ terms.
Then, by Inclusion-Exclusion theory, the computation in (1) above is equivalent to
$$\sum_{r=0}^8 (-1)^r T_r.$$
Clearly $~T_0 = | ~S ~| = 8!.$
For $~r \in \{1,2,\cdots,8\},~$ considerations of symmetry greatly simplify the computation of $~T_r.~$
That is, for a specific value of $~r,~$ each of the $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{r} ~$ terms represents having $~r~$ forced couplings, where exactly $~r~$ of the camels are forced to be directly behind a specific camel.  Each such coupling may be regarded as a fused unit, so that instead of permuting $~8~$ units, you are permuting $~(8-r)~$ units.
Therefore,
$$\sum_{r=0}^8 (-1)^r T_r$$
$$= \sum_{r = 0}^8 (-1)^r \binom{8}{r} (8-r)!,$$
which agrees with the official solution.

I had conjured up a scenario where there were very large boxes that could accomodate upto $8$ camels laterally (which you are calling fused units, but gave up the concept as too bizarre for a caravan.

Just fyi: I've copied the literal question from the book in place of OP.  Your reverse-engineered interpretation is correct, but I thought you should know the question language was updated.
